# Как добавить каждой точке графика свою всплывающую картинку chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Собственно сам вопрос, можно ли как то добавить для каждой точки графика в chart.js свою уникальную картинку, которая будет появляться в tooltip

Comment: документация не помогает ?

Comment: Ну если бы помогла, не писал бы